# spring jpa not saving entity after first save call

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-boot, transactions

saving three entities into the table respectively.

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public Account save(JoinVO vo) throws MessagingException{

        Account account = converter.convert(vo, Account.class);
        AccountProfile profile = converter.convert(vo, AccountProfile.class);
        account.setProfile(profile);
        profile.setAccount(account);

        AccountSecurity security = AccountSecurity.of(1, 0, 0);
        security.setActivateKey(randomGenerator.generate(255));
        account.setSecurity(security);
        security.setAccount(account);

        account = repository.save(account);
        accountProfileService.save(profile);
        accountSecurityService.save(security);

        emailContext.sendJoinApprovalMessage(account.getEmail(), account.getProfile().getNickname(), account.getSecurity().getActivateKey());

        return account;
    }
```

and here is my entities:

Account entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="account_seq"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="email")
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="account_seq", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private int accountId;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=false, unique=true)
    @NonNull
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JoinColumn(name="account_seq", referencedColumnName="account_seq")
    private AccountProfile profile;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JoinColumn(name="account_seq", referencedColumnName="account_seq")
    private AccountSecurity security;
}
```

AccountProfile entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_profile", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"account_seq"}),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"nickname"})
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
public class AccountProfile {

    @Id
    @Column(name="account_seq", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private int accountId;

    @Column(name="nickname", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private String nickname;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="profile")
    private Account account;


}
```

Account Security Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_security", uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="account_seq")
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class AccountSecurity {


    @Id
    @Column(name="account_seq", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int accountId;

    @NonNull
    private Integer enabled;

    @NonNull
    private Integer activated;

    @Column(name="activate_key", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String activateKey;

    @Column(name="login_failed", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private Integer loginFailed;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="security")
    private Account account;


}
```

When I run the code, the first save was made successfully, but there are no logs of inserting into second, third table with data.

I googled and it says I have to tag @Transactional annotation to where I want to update DB storage. But still no luck. What am I missing here ??

Beside, I am using Spring Boot and JPA, mysql 5.7.

**CASE CLOSED.
I changed my entity information and it worked smoothly.**

Account - deleted PrimaryJoinKeyColumn and 'mapped-by' link's owner changed

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="account_seq"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="email")
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="account_seq", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private Integer accountId;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=false, unique=true)
    @NonNull
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="account")
    private AccountProfile profile;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="account")
    private AccountSecurity security;
}
```

AccountProfile - deleted PrimaryJoinKeyColumn and 'mapped-by' link's owner changed

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_profile", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"account_seq"}),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"nickname"})
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
public class AccountProfile implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="account_seq", referencedColumnName="account_seq")
    private Account account;

    @Column(name="nickname", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private String nickname;

}
```

AccountSecurity -deleted PrimaryJoinKeyColumn and 'mapped-by' link's owner changed

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_security", uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="account_seq")
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class AccountSecurity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="account_seq", referencedColumnName="account_seq")
    private Account account;

    @NonNull
    private Integer enabled;

    @NonNull
    private Integer activated;

    @Column(name="activate_key", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String activateKey;

    @Column(name="login_failed", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private Integer loginFailed;

}
```

and I changed the logic to save all the relative entities using one Account repository, not AccountProfileRepository nor AccountSecurityRepository.

AccountService.save() is below:

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public boolean save(JoinVO vo) throws MessagingException{

        Account account = converter.convert(vo, Account.class);

        AccountProfile profile = converter.convert(vo, AccountProfile.class);
        profile.setAccount(account);
        account.setProfile(profile);

        AccountSecurity security = AccountSecurity.of(1, 0, 0);
        security.setActivateKey(randomGenerator.generate(255));
        security.setAccount(account);
        account.setSecurity(security);

        account = repository.save(account);

        emailContext.sendJoinApprovalMessage(account.getEmail(), profile.getNickname(), security.getActivateKey());

        return (account != null);
    }
```

Comment: A few questions: you are using `entitymanager.persist` for saving? Normally just saving `account` should be enough! what are the transactional attributes of the save-methods? Did you try without `mappedBy`, since using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` should be enough information for the mapper on owner side? What happens, if you set the owned object- primary keys also by a generatedvalue?

Comment: thank you for your response. I updated entity information  and it works fine :). I will edit this post again for others to see.

Comment: @aschoerk I just tagged PrimaryKeyJoinColumn without knowing what is this annotation means befoore, and I tried "mappedBy" to opposite case, it works thanks. And Transactional has default attributes.